# Applying shading to character styles using Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created the following subroutine (and used a function from VBA Express) to assign shading and a keyboard shortcut to a Word style. This code works fine for a paragraph style or a linked style, and it works fine for assigning a keyboard shortcut to a character style, but the line that assigns shading throws a 4198 error if the style is a character style (any character style - I've used "Emphasis" here).

Is there something that needs to be adjusted to be able to apply shading to a character style via VBA? Thanks in advance!

I've tried this with a variety of styles and the character style appears to be the key issue.

```
Sub Format_Style()
    Dim sStyle As String
    sStyle = "Emphasis"
    If StyleExists(sStyle) Then
       CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument
       KeyBindings.add wdKeyCategoryStyle, sStyle, BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyAlt, wdKeyH)
       ActiveDocument.Styles(sStyle).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
       ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles
       Else
            MsgBox ("There is no style '" & sStyle & "' in this document.")
    End If
End Sub

Function StyleExists(StyleName As String) As Boolean
'from: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?15259-Solved-How-to-check-if-a-Word-Style-exists

    Dim MyStyle As Word.Style
    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles(StyleName)
    ' Set MyStyle = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Styles(StyleName)
    StyleExists = Not MyStyle Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shading isn't a property of the style. It is a property of either the paragraph format or the font, depending on the type of style. If you don't know what type of style sStyle is you could use the following code to set the shading.

```
  With ActiveDocument.Styles(sStyle)
    If .Type = wdStyleTypeCharacter Then
      .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    ElseIf .Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Or .Type = wdStyleTypeLinked Then
      .ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    End If
  End With
```

EDIT:
You should also check your usage of `ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles` as this probably isn't doing what you think it is. The `UpdateStyles` method copies styles from the attached template and overwrites those in the document that have the same name. [See the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.updatestyles)

Comment: @MichaelSchuler If this has solved your issue please accept as the answer to help others with the same question.